# HTML Accordion 50/50 split screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to HTML5 and CSS3 so apologies if this is a stupid question…

Looking at the image below, what I am trying to do is have something where the page is split 50 / 50, if the user clicks on the top arrow the top part shrinks and the bottom takes most of the space, alternatively if the user clicks the bottom arrow to shrink the bottom then the top takes most of the space

I can’t figure out what to do, please help
[image]

Comment: You will want to add the javascript tag as I expect that will be needed.

Comment: Yes you can do this, though you'll need a little Javascript - I'd suggest reading up on the JQuery toggle class, which allows you to add or subtract a CSS class to an HTML element after a Javascript event, such as a click. http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-toggleclass-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Please find the working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5Fn43/1/)

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3>Section 1</h3>
 <div>
<p>
Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
</p>
</div>
<h3>Section 2</h3>
<div>
 <p>
Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
suscipit faucibus urna.
</p>
</div>

</div>

 $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
```

Comment: It is, could you tell me what are you doing?

Comment: Ah, sorry. It was my mistake. I was clicking on the top button expecting it to shrink the top div.. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://jqueryui.com/

In the left column under widgets you will see accordian, look into that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser/client-side handled event, so you will need a basic understanding of **JavaScript** and more preferably also **jQuery**. You can achieve it in different ways, but for the sake of simple and nice example I will only go over the nice and easy way.

You can trigger a jQuery on click event (click() method) and toggle the top DIV's visibility.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4gRH/) or for a more fancy way see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gbyD/).

The jQuery methods used are

```
$(element).toggle();
$(element).slideToggle();
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/?s=toggle